# OctoberCms component: How to display all ID(items) instead of sorting only one ID?

Tags: php, plugins, octobercms

I'm building an job application plug-in in OctoberCms. Now only 1 of the 2 items apear on the front-end. I would like all the items to display. But now I can only select 1 by imput the id in the backend at the component propperty

I have to add this`$properties = $this->getProperties();` somewhere in my code but I can't figure out where. any suggestions?

```
php namespace Hessel\Vacatures\Components;

use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Hessel\Vacatures\Models\Vacature as VacatureModel;

class vacature extends ComponentBase
{

    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'Vacature Component',
            'description' => 'No description provided yet...'
        ];
    }

     public function defineProperties()
    {
        return [
            'vacatureId' => [
                'title'        => 'Vacature'

            ],
        ];

    }

     public function getVacatureIdOptions()
    {
        return VacatureModel::select('id', 'title')->orderBy('title')->get()->lists('title', 'id');
    }

    public function onRender()
    {
        $this->vacature = $this->page['vacature'] = VacatureModel::where('id', '=', $this -> property('vacatureId')) -> first();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `onRender()` you use ->first() at the end. if you change this to ->get() This returns an Object with all values for each row. you should loop through it to print them out ofcourse.

```
public function onRender()
{
    $object = VacatureModel::where('id', '=', $this -> property('vacatureId')) -> get();
}
```

`foreach($object as $key => $value){
  echo $value->id;
}`

Comment: Can you give me an example of the looping?

Comment: tnx for the help!! =D

Comment: If the answer was correct please mark it so further readers can spot it! Your welcome!